# GROUP BY using substring?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by, count

I have the following table:

```
t1:
id                item
--------------------------
XR-2017-432       car
XR-2019-736       car
BC-2017-847       motorbike
XR-2017-937       car
BC-2020-758       motorbike
GK-2019-823       boat
GK-2017-928       boat
XR-2018-438       car
```

And I want to count the number of occurences of each year. 
The answer of the query should be this:

```
result:
year        count
-------------------
2017        4
2018        1
2019        2
2020        1
```

How can I do this with a MySQL query?

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
select substr(id, 4, 4) yr, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by yr
order by yr
```

`substr(id, 4, 4)` extracts the relevant part of the string (4 characters starting from the 4th character in the string), which you can then use for grouping).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1b8bb8d33aa13ec9c657b7c1a4dab6e0)**:

```
yr   | cnt
:--- | --:
2017 |   4
2018 |   1
2019 |   2
2020 |   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `substring_index`.

```
select 
   substring_index(substring_index(mt, "-",  -2), "-", 1) as year, 
   count(*) as count
from yourTable
group by 
    year
```